# Meteor.js android version code

Tags: javascript, android, meteor

In the mobile-config.js I have specified following

```
App.info({
    .....
    version: '1.0.8',
    ....
});


App.setPreference('android-versionCode', '9');
```

Accordingly when I build apk it should have versionCode set to 9 and version name to "1.0.8', but in my case versionCode is being set to "10008" while version name is correctly shown as "1.0.8".

Is there something wrong in my config? Is there different method to version Code?

Comment: I'm using meteor 1.1.0.3 and find that using `version: '0.0.10'` generates an `android-versionCode=10` in the _AndroidManifest.xml_, so you can use this setting (without `App.setPreference('android-versionCode', '9');`). Hope it helps.

Comment: The 8 at the end of your versionCode is a [bug still in Cordova](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32951375/why-does-cordova-phonegap-append-8-to-my-android-version-code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override meteor build files and setting by creating a top level folder called `/cordova-build-override/`, read more here `errr, GitHub is down, I will post a link when it is back`.

Solution is to pass Android build settings to `build-extras.gradle`. You can read more here [Android Shell Tool Guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide/platforms/android/tools.html).

Create `/cordova-build-override/platforms/android/build-extras.gradle`. 
The Android *Version Name* will be set in `mobile-config.js` but the *Version Number (Integer)* will be set by this gradle file.

```
cdvVersionCode = '10'
android {
  lintOptions {
      disable 'MissingTranslation'
      disable 'ExtraTranslation'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

As of Meteor 1.4.2 you can specify buildNumber in App.info within the mobile-config.js file. See example below

App.info({
  id: '',
  name: '',
  description: '',
  version: '0.5.6',
  buildNumber: '5060',
  author: '',
  email: '',
  website: ''
});

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a good answer for this yet but by importing the project into Android Studio and editing `project/manifests/AndroidManifest.xml` you can change the version code. You have to rebuild of course. It appears `android-versionCode` sets the version code of the `CordvaLib` project but not `project`. The Gradle build script will still add an 8 to the end of it though. You can find where it does that pretty easily if you want to tweak it (Search for cdvVersionCode). Seems stupid to have to do any of this though and I just wanted to get something to the beta testers.

Answer (score 0):

I may be pretty late to the party here, but the  simplest solution is to set the build number in your `App.info({ ... })` at the top of the `mobile-config.js`.