# Playstore Phonegap android version code mismatch

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I have built my app using the phonegap build service. When I first published my app I had the following versions for android

```
    versionCode =   "1"
    version     =    "1.0.0"
```

They showed up properly on the playstore.

When publishing an update I updated the versions as follows

```
    versionCode =   "2"
    version     =    "1.0.1"
```

But immediately after publishing the playstore dashboard shows versions as

```
    version = 28(1.0.1)
```

Where is the **28** coming from?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32951375/why-does-cordova-phonegap-append-8-to-my-android-version-code

Answer (score 1):

On Phonegap Build whenever you rebuild the app, android version code auto-increases. However, you can set the build version by setting 'versionCode'

> http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
>   3           xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
>   4           id = "com.organization.appName" versionCode="2" version   = "1.0.0">

Comment: din't work? Set Version code to a higher number (60 or 70)and check whether it works. This is NOT the version number shown to users. This number is used only to determine whether one version is more recent than another. So don't worry about this.