# Cordova versionCode appends 8 after build

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-gradle-plugin

I am building for Android using Cordova with Ionic. I have set the versionCode in the widget tag inside the config.xml file to **10**. But after building the app I am getting the version code as **108**.

The version of Cordova that I have is 6.1.1.

How can I build an app where the versionCode is unchanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This still seems to be an unresolved issue in Cordova since version 5.0. Check out this [issue link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/CB-8976) for more info on the same.

Also I suggest you to look at the following [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32951375/why-does-cordova-phonegap-append-8-to-my-android-version-code) for possible resolution of the issue.

Comment: Is there a tag in config file that I can add to solve this like PhoneGap build has a `android-versioncode` preference which overrides what is set in the widget attribute..see this https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2210856

Comment: Also, the greatest value allowed by playstore for versionCode is `2100000000` So if it keeps on adding 8 at the end I will be able to update my app only 9 times..

Comment: @krv did you checked the so post link I mentioned?? This issue seems to be fixed in Cordova-android-5.2.0 as per the latest comments. Check out. Else you may have to tweak build.gradle.file I dont think we have any readymade tag to fix it in config.xml

Comment: I checked the cordova version which is 6.2.0..How do I update `cordova-android`?